# Unable to run a query to return information based on 3 different conditions on exchange shell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010, selectedindexchanged, exchange-server-2007

Somewhat new to exchange shell. I'm wanting to run a query to return exchange resource/equipment mailboxes that matches certain conditions

```
Get-mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails RoomMailbox, EquipmentMailbox | foreach-object {Get-CalendarProcessing $_.alias | select identity, AllowConflicts, ConflictPercentageAllowed, MaximumConflictInstances | where {($_.MaximumConflictInstances >=1) -and ($_.AllowConflicts -eq $true) -and ($_.ConflictPercentageAllowed >=1)}}  | export-csv h:\test12346.csv
```

But I'm getting this below error

```
out-file : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\=1' is denied.
At line:1 char:212
+ ... nces | where {($_.MaximumConflictInstances >=1) -and ($_.AllowConflicts -eq $tru ...
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand
```

I know potentially or my condition syntaxes are incorrect for the MaximumConflictInstances and or AllowConflicts paramters because when I ran the below command (partially of initial command), it works fine as expected

```
Get-mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails RoomMailbox, EquipmentMailbox | foreach-object {Get-CalendarProcessing $_.alias | select ide
ntity, AllowConflicts, ConflictPercentageAllowed, MaximumConflictInstances | where {($_.AllowConflicts -eq $true)}}  | export-csv h:\allowC.csv
```

I've tried the below and now appears I'm missing something. Is someone able to help me review my code and advise what I'm missing?

```
Get-mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails RoomMailbox, EquipmentMailbox | foreach-object {Get-CalendarProcessing $_.alias | select identity, AllowConflicts, ConflictPercentageAllowed, MaximumConflictInstances | where {($_.AllowConflicts -eq $true)  -and  {($_.MaximumConflictInstances -gt 1) -OR ($_.ConflictPercentageAllowed -gt 1)}}  | export-csv h:\test12346.csv
```

Long story short, im just trying to export all exchange room objects and equipment objects if their paramters - allowconflicts is set to TRUE, and MaximumConflictInstances & ConflictPercentageAllowed  is equals to OR greater than 1 for both

Thanks
Rob

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something meaningful. Your title should describe the question you're asking or problem you're having, and be descriptive enough to be of use to a future reader scanning a list of search results. *Need help advice* is not useful, and  *2013 exchange cmdlet* is not a problem description or question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When doing a comparison, PowerShell does not use the ">=" comparison operator. It should look like this:

```
where-object { ($_.MaximumConflictInstances -ge 1) -and ($_.AllowConflicts -eq $true) -and ($_.ConflictPercentageAllowed -ge 1)}
```

You can review the PowerShell comparison operators here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6

Comment: getting "a parameter cannot be found that mtches paramter name 'AND' error message
Get-mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails RoomMailbox, EquipmentMailbox | foreach-object {Get-CalendarProcessing $_.alias | select ide
ntity, AllowConflicts, ConflictPercentageAllowed, MaximumConflictInstances | where {($_.AllowConflicts -eq $true)}  -AND {($_.MaximumConflictInstances
-ge 1) -OR ($_.ConflictPercentageAllowed -ge 1)}}  | export-csv h:\test12346.csv
foreach-object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'AND'.
At line:1 char:67

Comment: It looks like you have changed your formatting of the command based on what you shared above. In your `where` clause you use an opening curly brach "{" but then close it after the first comparison check `{($_.AllowConflicts -eq $true)}`. When PowerShell sees this, it treats the `-AND` as a new parameter.